# Converting Character Column into DateTime with cols_only in R Results in NA

Tags: r, type-conversion, datetime-format

I am attempting to change the data type of a column in R with cols_only.

I have been asked to include the first few rows of data:

```
ride_id rideable_type   started_at  ended_at    total_ride_time day_of_week start_station_name  start_station_id    end_station_name    end_station_id  start_lat   start_lng   end_lat end_lng member_casual
550CF7EFEAE0C618    electric_bike   8/7/22 9:34 PM  8/7/22 9:41 PM  0:07:31 2                   41.93   -87.69  41.94   -87.72  casual
DAD198F405F9C5F5    electric_bike   8/8/22 2:39 PM  8/8/22 2:53 PM  0:14:02 2                   41.89   -87.64  41.92   -87.64  casual
E6F2BC47B65CB7FD    electric_bike   8/8/22 3:29 PM  8/8/22 3:40 PM  0:10:44 2                   41.97   -87.69  41.97   -87.66  casual
F597830181C2E13C    electric_bike   8/8/22 2:43 AM  8/8/22 2:58 AM  0:15:03 1                   41.94   -87.65  41.97   -87.69  casual
0CE689BB4E313E8D    electric_bike   8/7/22 8:24 PM  8/7/22 8:29 PM  0:05:52 2                   41.85   -87.65  41.84   -87.66  casual
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
trip_data_202208 <- read_csv(("202208_divvy_tripdata.csv"), 
  col_types = cols_only(ride_id = col_character(), 
  rideable_type = col_character(), started_at = col_datetime(), 
  ended_at = col_character(), 
  total_ride_time = col_time(format = ""), 
  day_of_week = col_character(), 
  start_station_name = col_character(), 
  start_station_id = col_character(), 
  end_station_name = col_character(), 
  end_station_id = col_character(), 
  start_lat = col_double(), 
  start_lng = col_double(), end_lat = col_double(), 
  end_lng = col_double(),member_casual = col_character() 
    )
      )
```

The only data types I'm changing are "started_at" and "total_ride_time." The total ride time column does successfully change and outputs a time throughout the column. However, the started at column returns with NA throughout the column.

I have also tried other datetime functions such as POSIXct from other tutorials and posts without success.

I'm aware that this is a simple task, but I'm really struggling. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: There's nothing we can do without sample data. Please post at least the first few lines of your CSV file into a code block in your question.

Comment: @r2evans I believe I have added the sample data you were asking for.

Comment: No, you provided an incomplete sample of some columns, some of each, and all already parsed. I suggested the raw CSV so that we can confirm what Dave2e suggested, that the raw unparsed format is nonstandard.

Comment: Okay I added the raw data from the csv. @r2evans

Comment: Your file is not CSV, which stands for comma-separated values. Your table is something else: it's not quite fixed-width format (fwf). Further, because some of the fields have embedded spaces (`started_at` and `ended_at`), we can't use `read_delim` or the normal table variants. Whatever process created this file is doing it poorly; while it might be feasible to read it in, I think the better answer is to remove ambiguity in the data and fix the originating process.

Answer (score 0):

This works only if your file is actually tab-delimited; if those are really just spaces (imposed by a limitation in the Stack interface), then there is no easy way to get at everything unambiguously.

Issues:

1. Use `read_delim`, as this file is not a CSV, so `read_csv` is out.
2. The timestamp columns are not unambiguous, we need to use `col_datetime(format="%m/%d/%y %H:%S %p")`.
3. It appears that there are more column headers than columns. I suspect we're missing all `*_station_*` fields. I'll remove the `col_*` for these columns, hoping that you have it in your real data and just truncated your sample. If you've done nothing to alter the file, then your data is incomplete/broken, go back to whomever/whatever gave it to you.

```r
out <- readr::read_delim("~/Downloads/202208_divvy_tripdata.csv", 
  delim = "\t", col_types = cols_only(ride_id = col_character(), 
  rideable_type = col_character(), started_at = col_datetime(format="%m/%d/%y %H:%S %p"), 
  ended_at = col_datetime(format="%m/%d/%y %H:%S %p"), 
  total_ride_time = col_time(format = ""), 
  day_of_week = col_character(), 
  start_lat = col_double(), 
  start_lng = col_double(), end_lat = col_double(), 
  end_lng = col_double(),member_casual = col_character()))
# A tibble: 5 × 11
  ride_id          rideable_type started_at          ended_at            total_ride_time day_of_week start_lat start_lng end_lat end_lng member_casual
  <chr>            <chr>         <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>          <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>        
1 550CF7EFEAE0C618 electric_bike 2022-08-07 21:00:34 2022-08-07 21:00:41 07'31"          2                41.9     -87.7    41.9   -87.7 casual       
2 DAD198F405F9C5F5 electric_bike 2022-08-08 14:00:39 2022-08-08 14:00:53 14'02"          2                41.9     -87.6    41.9   -87.6 casual       
3 E6F2BC47B65CB7FD electric_bike 2022-08-08 15:00:29 2022-08-08 15:00:40 10'44"          2                42.0     -87.7    42.0   -87.7 casual       
4 F597830181C2E13C electric_bike 2022-08-08 02:00:43 2022-08-08 02:00:58 15'03"          1                41.9     -87.6    42.0   -87.7 casual       
5 0CE689BB4E313E8D electric_bike 2022-08-07 20:00:24 2022-08-07 20:00:29 05'52"          2                41.8     -87.6    41.8   -87.7 casual
```

---

File content with tabs (in case I'm correct, so that others can reproduce this if needed), noting that I've removed the headers for `*_station_*` due to missing data:

```r
c("ride_id\trideable_type\tstarted_at\tended_at\ttotal_ride_time\tday_of_week\tstart_lat\tstart_lng\tend_lat\tend_lng\tmember_casual", 
"550CF7EFEAE0C618\telectric_bike\t8/7/22 9:34 PM\t8/7/22 9:41 PM\t0:07:31\t2\t41.93\t-87.69\t41.94\t-87.72\tcasual", 
"DAD198F405F9C5F5\telectric_bike\t8/8/22 2:39 PM\t8/8/22 2:53 PM\t0:14:02\t2\t41.89\t-87.64\t41.92\t-87.64\tcasual", 
"E6F2BC47B65CB7FD\telectric_bike\t8/8/22 3:29 PM\t8/8/22 3:40 PM\t0:10:44\t2\t41.97\t-87.69\t41.97\t-87.66\tcasual", 
"F597830181C2E13C\telectric_bike\t8/8/22 2:43 AM\t8/8/22 2:58 AM\t0:15:03\t1\t41.94\t-87.65\t41.97\t-87.69\tcasual", 
"0CE689BB4E313E8D\telectric_bike\t8/7/22 8:24 PM\t8/7/22 8:29 PM\t0:05:52\t2\t41.85\t-87.65\t41.84\t-87.66\tcasual"
)
```